# How to make the confidence interval (error bands) show on seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, continuous-integration, seaborn

I'm trying to create a plot of classification accuracy for three ML models, depending on the number of features used from the data (the number of features used is from 1 to 75, ranked according to a feature selection method). I did 100 iterations of calculating the accuracy output for each model and for each "# of features used". Below is what my data looks like (clsf from 0 to 2, timepoint from 1 to 75):
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyTf0.png)

I am then calling the seaborn function as shown in documentation files.

```
sns.lineplot(x= "timepoint", y="acc", hue="clsf", data=ttest_df, ci= "sd", err_style = "band")
```

The plot comes out like this: 
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmgSv.png)

I wanted there to be confidence intervals for each point on the x-axis, and don't know why it is not working. I have 100 y values for each x value, so I don't see why it cannot calculate/show it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try your data set using Seaborn's `pointplot` [function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) instead. It's specifically for showing an indication of uncertainty around a scatter plot of points.  By default `pointplot` will connect values by a line. This is fine if the categorical variable is ordinal in nature, but it can be a good idea to remove the line via `linestyles = ""` for nominal data. *(I used `join = False` in my example)*

I tried to recreate your notebook to give a visual, but wasn't able to get the confidence interval in my plot exactly as you describe.  I hope this is helpful for you.

[image]

```
sb.set(style="darkgrid")
sb.pointplot(x = 'timepoint', y = 'acc', hue = 'clsf',
            data = ttest_df, ci = 'sd', palette = 'magma', 
            join = False);
```

[image]